# Concurrent Timeout exception on starting Jboss Wildfly 9.02 server

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I am new to jboss server. When I am trying to deploy .war file on server the following exception gets print on console:

```
6:38:04,388 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]'
16:38:05,642 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = Aerobay.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
16:38:09,548 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@5f88823f for operation {"operation" => "add-deployer-chains","address" => []} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:396)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1384)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1332)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1292)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1180)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.handleContainerStabilityFailure(AbstractOperationContext.java:964)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:590)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:354)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:330)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1183)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:453)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:313)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:384)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:359)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem when I tried to deploy the WAR file on my Red Hat Jboss EAP 7.0.

But the server was integrated into my IDE (Eclipse Neon) and the problem only occured in Debug-Modus.

I was able to solve the problem by removing all breakpoints and after that i started the server again.

Comment: After updating to neon today I am also seeing this sporadically with WildFly 10 also, but unfortunately even when I have no breakpoints set. I am using JRebel, which might contribute however. For the time being, I think I will go back to Mars.2, which was working well and quite stable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment ... I forgot to mention that I started the server in "standard" mode before... (that worked very well). After that I removed all breakpoints and started the server again. And the problem disappeared.

Comment: Same issue with IJ, JRebel and wildfly 8. Remove breakpoints and restart solved it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm really pleased! Thank you very much for your vote! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I started facing this in last couple of day, would have never able to guess its because of break points in IJ. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Try increasing timeout by adding java option "blocking.timeout". You can do it in bin/standalone.conf.bat (depends on how you configure wildfly) by adding line: 
**set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=600**
Change the number if it's not enough.

Comment: does the increase really solve the problem?

Answer (score 9):

increasing the timeout doesn't solve the root cause of the problem. You need to check the cause of the time of the block and solve the issue. Maybe in some cases the solution is to increase the timeout.

In most cases, increasing resources is a bad way to solve issues. I had this case, the Wildfly took a lot of time to boot. I increased the timeout to 600 and solved the issue but was still having issue with the wildfly booting time which was so annoying.

```
2018-03-26 07:50:36,523 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[("path" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")]'
```

Finally I checked the block cause in and found the block was due to network host resolving (NAS storage defined as a path in wildfly).

I jumped to the network setting and found that my local DNS was not set properly. I added the local DNS instead of the public DNS and the block issue was gone. Hope this helps

Regards
Sleem

Comment: I think a part of cases are due to network problems too when changing timeout or resources does not solve the situation. It is also my case ... Because I see network error when enabling TRACE log. But cannot see how to resolve them for the moment ...

Answer (score 4):

When i tried to debug and started the server with debug mode got the following error:

```
16:19:50,096 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS013412: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "ViprWeb.war")]'
16:19:50,096 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS015870
16:20:00,117 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS013413: Timeout after [5000] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation.
```

I removed all my breakpoints and restarted my server jboss and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Months I've (with the help of team members from time to time) been trying to resolve this issue, literally months. Been running wildfly from the command line in the mean time. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

just increase time out in **standalone.conf.bat**
set as **set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=600**
It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem running a "dockerized" application locally - turns out increasing the resources fixed the issue. What I finally settled on:
CPUs: 4
Memory: 8GB
Swap: 2GB

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, with netbeans

but I had not break points.
Running jboss by command line, helped me

- Stop jboss
- Close Netbeans
- open command line
- Go to jboss folder > bin >
- type: standalone.bat (this starts jboss)
- open Netbeans
- worked fine!

  Hope it'll help someone else.

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem and i am using MyEclipse

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing the same problem recently with WildFly 18 and 21, trying to run a WAR file containing JSR-352 batch jobs that worked fine on WildFly 14.

Increasing the timeout did not solve the situation, only prolonged the time before the TimeoutException was casted, no matter the value (e.g. 5, 10 or 20 minutes).

I've just found that to turn off `microprofile-metrics-smallrye`subsystem seems to be a possible solution.

After commenting out this line from the `standalone.xml` file, the war deploy was successful and much faster (about 2 minutes):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-metrics-smallrye:2.0" security-enabled="false" exposed-subsystems="*" prefix="${wildfly.metrics.prefix:wildfly}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having problem with keycloak server 15.0.2.

WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@410c55ac for operation add-deployer-chains at address [] failed

I am using mysql5.7 with jconnect8.0 jar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I killed the Kaspersky process and it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I tackled a similar problem and had only succeed with undeploy the the apps. This gave a clean environment for Wildfly to restart and start the management and http-service. Then deploy the apps/WARs and identify what got you to this state.

In my case it was transactions that wanted to recover and deleting those from DB solve the problem bot to re-occur.